# Why is my React component rendering twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm using `React-hooks` and the `Context API` for state management. I've console logged out the `context` state when the `consumer` component renders. In the `console` I noticed that the state from the `context` gets logged out twice. Why is that?

I'm using the `fetch API` to pull in data from my local `node` server. So, in the first few lines of the `console` I get the initial state of the `context` e.g `undefined`, `null` - then JUST below that, I get the updated state with the data pulled in from the server.

I've created a "Master" `context` to share `functions` that I'll use throughout the app. The `fetch` function is using `async/await`:

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';

export const MasterContext = createContext();

export class MasterProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        fetchData: async (url) => {
            let res = await fetch(url);
            let data = await res.json();
            return data;
        }
    }

    render() { 

        return ( 
            <MasterContext.Provider value={{...this.state}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </MasterContext.Provider>
         );
    }
}
```

I've got two components, using two different `contexts` - one `context` is real simple

```
state = {
        title: '',
        body: '',
        cta: {
            text: ''
        },
        img: '',
        setHeaderPromo: (res) => {
            this.setState({
                title: res[0].title,
                body: res[0].body,
                cta: {...this.state.cta, ...res[0].cta},
                img: res[0].img
            });
        }
    }
```

The data being pulled in for this component is just a simple `array` with a single `object`.

This is the `consumer` component:

```
const HeaderPromo = () => {
    const {title, body, cta, img, setHeaderPromo} = useContext(HeaderContext);
    const {fetchData} = useContext(MasterContext);

    useEffect(() => {

        fetchData(`http://localhost:5000/api/header`)
            .then((res) => {
                setHeaderPromo(res);
        });
    }, [fetchData, setHeaderPromo]);

    console.log(title);

    return ( 
        <article className="cp-header__promo">
            <div className="cp-header__promo__image">
                <img src={img} alt="promo"/>
            </div>
            <div className="cp-header__promo__copy">
                <h3>{title}</h3>
                <p>{body}</p>
                <button>{cta.text}</button>
            </div>
        </article>
     );
}
```

So, this technically works. However, I noticed that when I log out the `title` variable, it gets output twice. The first time it's the initial state of the `context`, the second time, it outputs the contents of the data. Why is it doing that?

My problem is with my second component - the `context` state is just an empty `array` that gets filled after the `fetch` request.

The second `context`:

```
 state = {
        albums: null,
        setNewReleases: (res) => {
            this.setState({
                albums: res
            });

        }
    }
```

These are the two `consumer` components:

```
const NewReleases = () => {

    const {albums, setNewReleases} = useContext(NewReleaseContext);
    const {fetchData} = useContext(MasterContext);

    useEffect(() => {

        fetchData(`http://localhost:5000/api/new-releases`)
            .then((res) => {
                setNewReleases(res);
            });

    }, [fetchData, setNewReleases]);

  console.log('from newRelease component', albums);

    return ( 
        <section className="cp-new-releases">
            <Row sectionHeading={`New Releases`} albums={albums}/>
        </section>
     );
}

export default NewReleases;
```

So, again, the `albums` variable gets logged out twice. first, the initial state, then the data gets pulled in, and it logs it again.

Now, I'm passing this `albums` variable down to the `<Row/>` component as a `prop`.

Row component:

```
const Row = ({sectionHeading, albums}) => {

    console.log('from row component', albums);

    return ( 
        <Fragment>
            <div className="cp-new-releases__row">
            {(sectionHeading) && (<h3 className="row-title">{sectionHeading}</h3>)}
                <div className="cp-new-releases__row__album-container">

                {albums.map((item, index) => (
                        <Album img={item.img} title={item.title} key={index}/>
                  ))}

                </div> 
            </div>
        </Fragment>
     );
}

export default Row;
```

Now the `albums` variable is an `array` containing two `objects`. If I try to loop through the `array`, its throws the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null`.

The only way I can get around this is by doing an `if` check to see if `albums` holds a value.

```
const Row = ({sectionHeading, albums}) => {

    console.log('from row component', albums);

    return ( 
        <Fragment>
            <div className="cp-new-releases__row">
            {(sectionHeading) && (<h3 className="row-title">{sectionHeading}</h3>)}
                <div className="cp-new-releases__row__album-container">
                  {(albums) ? (
                    albums.map((item, index) => (
                        <Album img={item.img} title={item.title} key={index}/>
                  ))
                  ) : (<p style={{color: 'red'}}>no album</p>)}
                </div> 
            </div>
        </Fragment>
     );
}

export default Row;
```

It's trying to loop through the initial state of the `context`. Can someone explain whats going on, and how I can improve my code?

I know this was long-winded. So, if you made it to the end, you're a champ.

Thanks

Comment: fetchData is async, so you have your initial render, and then another when the state is updated by the async completing.  you can check if albums is empty, and not render any child components, then when your fetch returns and sets albums, the render can then add your components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FetchData is an Async operation - so your issue is that you are adding the Row component before getting data from the server.  Hold off rendering `<Row>` until you have collected your albums.

```
return ( 
        <section className="cp-new-releases">
          { albums && // you might also want to test length here 
                      // - unless you want to show a message in your 
                      // Row component, indicating that non were found.
            <Row sectionHeading={`New Releases`} albums={albums}/>
          }
        </section>
     );
```

Now your Row element isnt created on initial load, but waits until you have got data, and then adds it.  Think of it like, calling a function,  you wouldnt call it unnecessarily, and only with valid data. Ultimately this is what you are doing when you add a component to a render function. So you have to add conditional logic, as Components are effectively functions, and should be invoked based on the logic of your particular use-case.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense now